# What to do with a corrupted ZFS rpool?

Tags: grub2, kernel, zfs

I have a corrupted rpool (appearing when updating Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04).
There is another thread with this title, except it seems that in the other thread, the ZFS pool is not corrupted...
[What to do about a corrupted ZFS Pool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99266/what-to-do-about-a-corrupted-zfs-pool?rq=1)

Basically, I have had troubles with my Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.2.0-36, first of network hardware not recognized, and now Ubuntu is simply freezing.

I still have the older kernel from 20.04, 5.15.0-88. That one works good. Ubuntu is not freezing, and I can write you this message. :)

So I wanted to set grub to load this last one by default.
I have been following this thread to do so:
[Set "older" kernel as default grub entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry)

Doing the step, and willing to update grub, with `sudo update-grub`, I get this error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_yismyo'.
```

So after some more search, I `zpool status`, and I get this status:

```
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:02 with 0 errors on Sun Nov 12 00:24:03 2023
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
      0c86e95c-1c25-624e-adf2-0428e3773eaa  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub in progress since Sun Nov 12 00:24:01 2023
    436G scanned at 246M/s, 403G issued at 227M/s, 436G total
    88K repaired, 92.37% done, 00:02:30 to go
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
      f3536666-f3e7-6245-8036-46f34b68f391  DEGRADED 1.12K     4     3  too many errors  (repairing)

errors: 1115 data errors, use '-v' for a list
```

Please, what should I do?
I am a complete newbie.
I have tried to find answers, but impossible to find how to "restore the entire pool from backup", and I don't think I have any backup (I mean if Ubntu is not doing one by default, this is clear I have not done so. I don't even know what is `rpool`, what it is supposed to do...)

Is my only option to re-install Ubuntu 22.04 from fresh?
This would not be my preferred one, I have files in some folder I would like to keep, but obviously, I can buy a 2nd external disk to keep this data away, and then format my current drive and make a fresh install.

Thanks for any help!