# Home Microserver using Ubuntu and ZFS: about ZFS

Tags: server, backup, raid, zfs

I see this topic is quite a popular ([[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82003/restoring-an-ubuntu-server-using-zfs-raidz-for-data), [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160729/which-version-of-ubuntu-is-best-for-home-media-server-and-nas)) so hopefully I can get nice feedback on what I'm trying to do. I'm buying an HP Microserver with 4x 2TB, and I currently have two computers. I'd like this microserver to become my "databank" in many respects:

1. I want to configure my computers so they can automatically backup to this box using the Ubuntu utility (Deja-Dup).
2. I want to install a Git server, a [local dropbox](http://owncloud.org/) and a media server (from what I know, either [Plex](https://plex.tv/), [xbmc](http://xbmc.org/) or [this post](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/), or any good suggestion)
3. Ideally, and because of the little I know about it, I'd like my filesystem to be ZFS and I also need help for configuring my `zpool` in the most efficient way.

#### About ZFS

I want my filesystem to be **fast in reading, very reliable** and to **support a single disk crash**, but I don't require it to be fast in writing. There are four disks, all 2TB - 7200rpm - 64MB cache. I want to make the most of them, in that respect for instance, plain mirroring doesn't seem to be the way to go. But I have no previous experience with ZFS, hence my request for help. I'm thinking of installing **Ubuntu Server 12.04** as my operating system, and use [ubuntu-zfs](https://launchpad.net/~zfs-native/+archive/stable).

- *How should I configure my zpool to make the most of my four 2TB HDDs?*

Many many thanks in advance, J

Comment: More information on ZFS and relation to RAID levels: http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/05/26/zfs-raid-levels/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [striped mirrored zpool](http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/06/03/howto-create-striped-mirror-vdev-pool/) (effectively RAID10). If you're on a budget you can also get away with a [raidz](http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/06/03/howto-create-raidz-zpool/) (effectively RAID5, but safer due to zfs checksums).

ZFS likes lots of RAM so be sure to fill up your server. With four disks you should easily saturate a 1Gbps LAN (sequential reads) and with only two computers on your network your read performance should be fine, but you can also consider [getting an SSD for L2ARC (read caching)](https://blogs.oracle.com/brendan/entry/test)

Answer (score 1):

To make the most of your 4x 2TB disks, and be able to survive a single drive failure, the obvious choice would be a pool with the 4 drives set up as a single RAIDZ VDEV. RAIDZ is essentially an advanced version of RAID-5, so you loose 1 drive 's worth of capacity to parity, which can be used to recover from losing any one drive in the array. RAIDZ provides quite decent read performance, especially on sequential reads, but write speed and random IO is not very impressive.